# viewing image from private Google Drive on HTML (google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script

Can I add image on html page from Google Drive (**Not public drive**) with Google Apps Script ?

With public drive, it's easy but I'm employee of compagny with Gsuite Entreprise.  Security prevents us from creating a shared drive open on the web.

Comment: I forgot ... it works on a PC but not on an iphone. I would like it to work on iphones as well.

Comment: Try converting the image to a dataUrl I have used them for background urls in webapps that are run solely on iphones.

Comment: You would need to use the API to retrieve the image while authenticated and then insert it into your page somehow, data URL is probably the best option. Can you share your code so far?

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo     I added this simple code in my index.html page.   <img src="https://drive.google.com/a/mydomain.com/thumbnail?id=imgID" width="100px">

I activated "Drive API" in Resources / Advanced Google Service.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code? More than just an `img` tag would be helpful.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>test image</title>    
  </head>
  <body>  

    <img src="https://drive.google.com/a/mydomain.com/thumbnail?id=1MoZLLCGSe1dqkGInxghoOmqYi-eByjoG" width="100px" alt="test image"> 
    
  </body>
</html>